# Add Group By in For-Loop

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I have a dataset as follows:

```
# Define Adstock Rate
adstock_rate = 0.50

# Create Data
advertising = c(117.913, 120.112, 125.828, 115.354, 177.090, 141.647, 137.892,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000, 
            0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000, 158.511, 109.385,  91.084,  79.253, 102.706, 
            78.494, 135.114, 114.549,  87.337, 107.829, 125.020,  82.956,  60.813,  83.149,   0.000,   0.000, 
            0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000, 129.515, 105.486, 111.494, 107.099,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000, 
            0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,
            134.913, 123.112, 178.828, 112.354, 100.090, 167.647, 177.892,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000, 
            0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000, 112.511, 155.385,  123.084,  89.253, 67.706, 
            23.494, 122.114, 112.549,  65.337, 134.829, 123.020,  81.956,  23.813,  65.149,   0.000,   0.000, 
            0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000, 145.515, 154.486, 121.494, 117.099,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000, 
            0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000
            )

Region = c(500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500,500, 500, 500, 500,500, 500, 500, 500,500, 500, 500, 500,500, 500, 500, 500,
       500, 500, 500, 500,500, 500, 500, 500,500, 500, 500, 500,500, 500, 500, 500,500, 500, 500, 500,500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
       500, 500,
       501, 501, 501, 501, 501, 501, 501, 501,501, 501, 501, 501,501, 501, 501, 501,501, 501, 501, 501,501, 501, 501, 501,
       501, 501, 501, 501,501, 501, 501, 501,501, 501, 501, 501,501, 501, 501, 501,501, 501, 501, 501,501, 501, 501, 501, 501, 501, 
       501, 501)

advertising_dataset<-data.frame(cbind(Region, advertising))
```

This is what the dataset looks like:

```
   Region advertising
1     500     117.913
2     500     120.112
3     500     125.828
4     500     115.354
5     500     177.090
6     500     141.647
7     500     137.892
8     500       0.000
9     500       0.000
10    500       0.000
11    500       0.000
12    500       0.000
13    500       0.000
14    500       0.000
15    500       0.000
16    500       0.000
17    500       0.000
18    500     158.511
19    500     109.385
20    500      91.084
```

From here, I am applying a lag function in which I take the first value, and then apply a for-loop to transform my dataset.

```
# Alternative Method Using Loops Proposed by Linh Tran
advertising_dataset$adstocked_advertising = numeric(length(advertising_dataset$advertising))
advertising_dataset$adstocked_advertising[1] = advertising_dataset$advertising[1]

for(i in 2:length(advertising_dataset$advertising)){
  advertising_dataset$adstocked_advertising[i] = advertising_dataset$advertising[i] + adstock_rate * advertising_dataset$adstocked_advertising[i-1]}
```

The issue I am having is that my dataset is separated by Region. I need to apply this function above (including taking the first value) by region.

Is there a way to do this with the dplyr package?

I know this is wrong but maybe something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
separated_by_region<- advertising_dataset %>%
group_by(Region) %>%
summarise(
advertising_dataset$adstocked_advertising = 
numeric(length(advertising_dataset$advertising))
advertising_dataset$adstocked_advertising[1] = 
advertising_dataset$advertising[1]

for(i in 2:length(advertising_dataset$advertising)){
  advertising_dataset$adstocked_advertising[i] = 
advertising_dataset$advertising[i] + adstock_rate * 
advertising_dataset$adstocked_advertising[i-1]})
```

Something along these lines. Not really sure how to do this.

I have a feeling I may have to use the split(advertising_dataset, advertising_dataset$Region) and use an apply function and rbind the results.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Example Output (but function needs to be applied by Region) 1 final dataset in the end:

```
  Region     advertising     adstocked_advertising
     500         117.913               117.9130000
     500         120.112               179.0685000
     500         125.828               215.3622500
     500         115.354               223.0351250
     500         177.090               288.6075625
     500         141.647               285.9507812
     500         137.892               280.8673906
     500           0.000               140.4336953
     500           0.000                70.2168477
     500           0.000                35.1084238
     500           0.000                17.5542119
     500           0.000                 8.7771060
     500           0.000                 4.3885530
     500           0.000                 2.1942765
     500           0.000                 1.0971382
     500           0.000                 0.5485691
     500           0.000                 0.2742846
     500         158.511               158.6481423
     500         109.385               188.7090711
     500          91.084               185.4385356
```

Comment: Can you give an example or mockup of what you want the output to look like?

Comment: Just provided. Thanks @camille. Your output should look the same as the one showing but when region 501 appears, the numbers should be different from my output.

Comment: follow-up question here if interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50372119/apply-2-for-loops-to-same-column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is really what you meant by using `dplyr`, or that this is better than a `do.call(rbind, lapply(...))` approach, but you could define a function like you've described above:

```
foo <- function(df_) {
  df_$adstocked_advertising = df_$advertising
  for (i in 2:nrow(df_)) {
    df_$adstocked_advertising[i] = df_$advertising[i] + adstock_rate * df_$adstocked_advertising[i - 1]
  }
  return(df_)
}
```

Then, use your piping to `group_by` region to apply the function to each group:

```
library(dplyr)

adv_2 <- data.frame(advertising_dataset %>%
  group_by(Region) %>%
  do(foo(data.frame(.))))


> adv_2[1:10,]
   Region advertising adstocked_advertising
1     500     117.913             117.91300
2     500     120.112             179.06850
3     500     125.828             215.36225
4     500     115.354             223.03512
5     500     177.090             288.60756
6     500     141.647             285.95078
7     500     137.892             280.86739
8     500       0.000             140.43370
9     500       0.000              70.21685
10    500       0.000              35.10842

> adv_2[50:60,]
   Region advertising adstocked_advertising
50    500       0.000              0.401496
51    500       0.000              0.200748
52    500       0.000              0.100374
53    501     134.913            134.913000
54    501     123.112            190.568500
55    501     178.828            274.112250
56    501     112.354            249.410125
57    501     100.090            224.795063
58    501     167.647            280.044531
59    501     177.892            317.914266
60    501       0.000            158.957133
```

Definitely would need a number check though, it does seem to match your output for the 500 group at least.

**Edit:**

As per comments, a version where the lag value is adjustable.

```
foo <- function(df_, lag_val = 1) {
  df_$adstocked_advertising = df_$advertising
  for (i in (1 + lag_val):nrow(df_)) {
    df_$adstocked_advertising[i] = df_$advertising[i] + adstock_rate * df_$adstocked_advertising[i - lag_val]
  }
  return(df_)
}
```

Default lag is still 1, but now you can change `lag_val` if you want to skip that many rows of the 'adstocked' column.

```
adv_2 <- data.frame(advertising_dataset %>%
  group_by(Region) %>%
  do(foo(data.frame(.), lag_val = 3)))

> adv_2
    Region advertising adstocked_advertising
1      500     117.913            117.913000
2      500     120.112            120.112000
3      500     125.828            125.828000
4      500     115.354            174.310500
5      500     177.090            237.146000
6      500     141.647            204.561000
7      500     137.892            225.047250
8      500       0.000            118.573000
9      500       0.000            102.280500
10     500       0.000            112.523625
```

I *think* that does what you want, but again definitely worth confirming. Hopefully it will help with the answer in your other linked question, but I'm guessing it will need some modification to be more flexible.

Cheers,

-Luke

Comment: I also asked a follow-up question if interested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50237076/for-loop-by-columns-with-existing-for-loop-by-rows

Comment: Also, @Luke C is there a way to make this more robust so that the lag can be a different value besides 1? The function fails when I make it 2 or 3.

Comment: I can also post a different question if you'd rather me do that. Whatever works best!

Comment: @NickKnauer - Yes, that's still doable but you'd need to account for the fact that the lag is 'skipped' for the first item in the array. I'll have a look to see if I can quickly make that change.

Comment: Ok thank you, I can also post another question if you'd rather me do that

Comment: @NickKnauer - No worries, I think it makes sense to keep here! Edited.