# For-Loop By Columns with existing For-loop by Rows

Tags: r, function, for-loop, dplyr, apply

I have a dataset as follows as a sample. My actual dataset has 5000 columns:

```
# Define Adstock Rate
adstock_rate = 0.50
lag_number = 3
# Create Data
advertising = c(117.913, 120.112, 125.828, 115.354, 177.090, 141.647, 137.892,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000, 
        0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000, 158.511, 109.385,  91.084,  79.253, 102.706, 
        78.494, 135.114, 114.549,  87.337, 107.829, 125.020,  82.956,  60.813,  83.149,   0.000,   0.000, 
        0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000, 129.515, 105.486, 111.494, 107.099,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000, 
        0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,
        134.913, 123.112, 178.828, 112.354, 100.090, 167.647, 177.892,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000, 
        0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000, 112.511, 155.385,  123.084,  89.253, 67.706, 
        23.494, 122.114, 112.549,  65.337, 134.829, 123.020,  81.956,  23.813,  65.149,   0.000,   0.000, 
        0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000, 145.515, 154.486, 121.494, 117.099,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000, 
        0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000
        )

advertising2 = c(43.913, 231.112, 76.828, 22.354, 98.090, 123.647, 90.892,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000, 
        0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000, 234.511, 143.385,  78.084,  89.253, 12.706, 
        34.494, 56.114, 78.549,  12.337, 67.829, 42.020,  90.956,  23.813,  83.149,   0.000,   0.000, 
        0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000, 52.515, 76.486, 89.494, 12.099,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000, 
        0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,
        67.913, 12.112, 45.828, 78.354, 89.090, 90.647, 23.892,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000, 
        0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000, 78.511, 23.385,  43.084,  67.253, 33.706, 
        56.494, 78.114, 98.549,  45.337, 31.829, 67.020,  87.956,  94.813,  65.149,   0.000,   0.000, 
        0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000, 55.515, 32.486, 78.494, 33.099,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000, 
        0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000,   0.000
        )
Region = c(500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500,500, 500, 500, 500,500, 500, 500, 500,500, 500, 500, 500,500, 500, 500, 500,
   500, 500, 500, 500,500, 500, 500, 500,500, 500, 500, 500,500, 500, 500, 500,500, 500, 500, 500,500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
   500, 500,
   501, 501, 501, 501, 501, 501, 501, 501,501, 501, 501, 501,501, 501, 501, 501,501, 501, 501, 501,501, 501, 501, 501,
   501, 501, 501, 501,501, 501, 501, 501,501, 501, 501, 501,501, 501, 501, 501,501, 501, 501, 501,501, 501, 501, 501, 501, 501, 
   501, 501)

advertising_dataset<-data.frame(cbind(Region, advertising, advertising2))
```

My dataset looks like this:

```
head(advertising_dataset, 15)

   Region advertising advertising2
1     500     117.913       43.913
2     500     120.112      231.112
3     500     125.828       76.828
4     500     115.354       22.354
5     500     177.090       98.090
6     500     141.647      123.647
7     500     137.892       90.892
8     500       0.000        0.000
9     500       0.000        0.000
10    500       0.000        0.000
11    500       0.000        0.000
12    500       0.000        0.000
13    500       0.000        0.000
14    500       0.000        0.000
15    500       0.000        0.000
```

A for-loop is then created to only *1* column and then a group_by function after that by `Region`.

```
foo <- function(df_, lag_val = 1) {
  df_$adstocked_advertising = df_$advertising
  for (i in (1 + lag_val):nrow(df_)) {
    df_$adstocked_advertising[i] = df_$advertising[i] + adstock_rate * 
df_$adstocked_advertising[i - lag_val]
  }
  return(df_)
}


adv_2 <- data.frame(advertising_dataset %>%
                      group_by(Region) %>%
                      do(foo(data.frame(.), lag_val = 3)))
```

How do I apply the above functions including `adv_2` to all columns from 2:ncol(advertising_dataset) rather than just the `advertising` column?

My final number of columns should double in the end because a newly revised column will be created for every existing column.

I have a feeling it is something along these lines, with the function I above:

```
data.frame(advertising_dataset[1], 
apply(advertising_dataset[2:ncol(advertising_dataset)],2, foo) )
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Please change your function to a working one when you change the `lag`

Comment: yeah I'm realizing the function is a mess when the lag is greater than 1. @akrun you can put your previous answer if you'd like and I'll accept that then. Going to have to look more into how to change the original function to ask this question again later. Didn't realize that.

Comment: The reason is that without knowing the expected output, it will take lots of time.  I undeleted it

Comment: thanks, will look further into how to make the function more robust

Comment: @akrun the function has been revised, would you like me to post a separate question regarding the lag function being adjusted?

Comment: this is great, thank you!

Comment: Final continuation of this question if interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50256439/multiple-variable-values-to-function-and-cbind-results

Comment: I posted a solution there

Comment: follow-up question here if interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50372119/apply-2-for-loops-to-same-column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `accumulate` with `mutate_all`

```
library(tidyverse)
out <- advertising_dataset %>% 
         group_by(Region) %>%
         mutate_all(funs(adstocked = accumulate(., ~ .y + adstock_rate * .x)))
out
# A tibble: 104 x 5
# Groups:   Region [2]
#   Region advertising advertising2 advertising_adstocked advertising2_adstocked
#    <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>                 <dbl>                  <dbl>
# 1    500        118.         43.9                 118.                    43.9
# 2    500        120.        231.                  179.                   253. 
# 3    500        126.         76.8                 215.                   203. 
# 4    500        115.         22.4                 223.                   124. 
# 5    500        177.         98.1                 289.                   160. 
# 6    500        142.        124.                  286.                   204. 
# 7    500        138.         90.9                 281.                   193. 
# 8    500          0           0                   140.                    96.4
# 9    500          0           0                    70.2                   48.2
#10    500          0           0                    35.1                   24.1
# ... with 94 more rows
```

---

Checking with the output from OP's solution

```
head(out[[4]])
#[1] 117.9130 179.0685 215.3623 223.0351 288.6076 285.9508

head(adv_2[[4]])
#[1] 117.9130 179.0685 215.3623 223.0351 288.6076 285.9508
```

#### Update

We could modify the OP's function `foo` for different `lag_val`

```
foo1 <- function(dot, lag_val = 1) {
     tmp <- dot
     for(i in (1 + lag_val): length(tmp)) {
           tmp[i] <- tmp[i] + adstock_rate * tmp[i - lag_val]
     }
     return(tmp)
   }


advertising_dataset %>%
       group_by(Region) %>%
       mutate_all(funs(adstocked = foo1(., lag_val = 1)))
# A tibble: 104 x 5
# Groups:   Region [2]
#   Region advertising advertising2 advertising_adstocked advertising2_adstocked
#    <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>                 <dbl>                  <dbl>
# 1    500        118.         43.9                 118.                    43.9
# 2    500        120.        231.                  179.                   253. 
# 3    500        126.         76.8                 215.                   203. 
# 4    500        115.         22.4                 223.                   124. 
# 5    500        177.         98.1                 289.                   160. 
# 6    500        142.        124.                  286.                   204. 
# 7    500        138.         90.9                 281.                   193. 
# 8    500          0           0                   140.                    96.4
# 9    500          0           0                    70.2                   48.2
#10    500          0           0                    35.1                   24.1
# ... with 94 more rows
```

-change the `lag_val`

```
advertising_dataset %>%
            group_by(Region) %>%
            mutate_all(funs(adstocked = foo1(., lag_val = 2)))
# A tibble: 104 x 5
# Groups:   Region [2]
#   Region advertising advertising2 advertising_adstocked advertising2_adstocked
#    <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>                 <dbl>                  <dbl>
# 1    500        118.         43.9                 118.                    43.9
# 2    500        120.        231.                  120.                   231. 
# 3    500        126.         76.8                 185.                    98.8
# 4    500        115.         22.4                 175.                   138. 
# 5    500        177.         98.1                 269.                   147. 
# 6    500        142.        124.                  229.                   193. 
# 7    500        138.         90.9                 273.                   165. 
# 8    500          0           0                   115.                    96.3
# 9    500          0           0                   136.                    82.3
#10    500          0           0                    57.3                   48.2
# ... with 94 more rows
```

Comment: This is fantastic! I have one question, I need to manually input the lag number, so for example the `[i-1]` is replaced by `[i-lag_number]`. With this code, is it possible to make this adjustable?

Comment: @NickKnauer  If you need a column with lag  You can do `mutate(newnumber = lag(row_number()))`

Comment: And does this also take into account making the first value of the revised column equal to the first value of the original?

Comment: @NickKnauer  That is the reason I compared with the output from your function.  It is getting the same result

Comment: Ok perfect, thanks. Can you revise your code to have the lag number be adjustable? I will look further into how to use the `funs` and `accumulate` function in the meantime so I can use this for future use.

Comment: @NickKnauer `all.equal(adv_2$adstocked_advertising, out[[4]])#
[1] TRUE`

Comment: @NickKnauer  Do you need `out %>% mutate(new = row_number()-1)`

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not following on that last comment

Comment: @NickKnauer  It is just to show that the output from your function is the same as the one I got

Comment: Sorry for all the questions, would you be able to adjust the code you provided so that in the part of `adstock_rate * .x`, `.x` is adjustable to be a lag of any input? Like `[i-lag_number]`.

Comment: @NickKnauer  In your function, you are doing a fixed `i - 1` and that is what the accumulate is also doing.  If you need to change it to more dynamic, then you should change your function

Comment: I've adjusted the question, to have this make more sense in this specific case

Comment: ok, sorry about that. The only difference is that the lag number needs to be adjustable.

Comment: Please correct your function so that it can take adjustable lag number.  Currently, it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Using data.table, you can apply any function to a subset of columns using an lapply within the j-statement. These functions will act on the columns as vectors, however, so you might want to edit your `foo()` to be general to any vector. But, basically, all you have to do is:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(advertising_dataset)
cnames <- colnames(advertising_dataset)
advertising_dataset[, lapply(.SD, foo), .SDcols = cnames[cnames != "Region]]
```

Comment: thanks @bk18, will look into how to make the function more general for a specified column. Not sure how to do that at the moment.