# Multiple Variable Values to Function and Cbind Results

Tags: r, for-loop, cbind

This is a continuation of this question here: 
[For-Loop By Columns with existing For-loop by Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50237076/for-loop-by-columns-with-existing-for-loop-by-rows)

I have a dataset in which I am using 3 variables: 
`adstock_rate`, `diminishing_rate`, and `lag_number`
. 
These are currently set to only 1 number each.

Currently I am using the following numbers:

```
adstock_rate<-0.5
lag_number<-1
diminishing_rate<-0.6
```

The final output is a dataset with new columns attached to the existing dataset using the function below.

```
foo1 <- function(dot, lag_val = 1) {
     tmp <- dot
     for(i in (1 + lag_val): length(tmp)) {
           tmp[i] <- tmp[i] + adstock_rate * diminishing_rate * tmp[i - lag_val]
     }
     return(tmp)
   }


advertising_dataset %>%
       group_by(Region) %>%
       mutate_all(funs(adstocked = foo1(., lag_val = lag_number)))
```

Here is what I am trying to do:

I want to apply this function to different values to these variables. Below are the combinations of these variables:

```
adstock_rate = c(0.50, 0.60, 0.70)
lag_number = c(0,1)
diminishing_rate = c(0.50, 0.60)

combos<-expand.grid(adstock_rate,lag_number,diminishing_rate)
colnames(combos)[1]<-"AdStock_Rate"
colnames(combos)[2]<-"Lag_Number"
colnames(combos)[3]<-"Diminish_Rate"


head(combos)

   AdStock_Rate Lag_Number Diminish_Rate
1           0.5          0           0.5
2           0.6          0           0.5
3           0.7          0           0.5
4           0.5          1           0.5
5           0.6          1           0.5
6           0.7          1           0.5
7           0.5          0           0.6
8           0.6          0           0.6
9           0.7          0           0.6
10          0.5          1           0.6
```

I think you would have to make a for-loop or use the apply function to go down the list of rows in the combos dataset.

Here is my attempt:

```
for(j in combos){
foo1 <- function(dot, lag_val = 1) {
     tmp <- dot
     for(i in (1 + lag_val): length(tmp)) {
           tmp[i] <- tmp[i] + combos[j,1] * combos[j,3] * tmp[i - lag_val]
     }
     return(tmp)
   }


advertising_dataset %>%
       group_by(Region) %>%
       mutate_all(funs(adstocked = foo1(., lag_val = combos[j,2])))

##cbind to previous output
}
```

I also need the column names to have the number values such as `adstock_0.5_1_0.6` where 0.5 = adstock rate, 1 = lag number, and diminishing = 0.6.

Hope this makes sense.

Please let me know if you need me to provide any more info.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we are looping through the rows of 'combos', create a `list` that have the same `length` as the number of rows of the 'combos' for storing the output from the `for` loop

```
lst <- vector("list", nrow(combos)) # initialize a list to store output
```

Add some more parameters in the 'foo1' for more flexibility

```
foo1 <- function(dot, lag_val = 1, combos, ind) {
     tmp <- dot
     for(i in (1 + lag_val): length(tmp)) {
           tmp[i] <- tmp[i] + combos[ind,1] * combos[ind,3] * tmp[i - lag_val]
     }
     return(tmp)
   }
```

and then loop through the rows of 'combos'

```
for(j in seq_len(nrow(combos))){

# assign the group by recursive output to each `list` element        


lst[[j]] <- advertising_dataset %>%
             group_by(Region) %>%
             mutate_all(funs(adstocked =
               foo1(., lag_val = combos[j,2], combos, ind = j)))

}
lst
```

It is not clear whether we need the `list` names to be 'adstock_Rate_Number_Drate' or not.  If that is that case,

```
names(lst) <- paste0("adstock_", do.call(paste, c(combos, sep="_")))
```

Convert the `list` of `data.frame` to a single data.frame having an 'id' column to indicate the combination

```
out <- bind_rows(lst, .id = 'id')
head(out, 3)
# A tibble: 3 x 6
# Groups:   Region [1]
#  id        Region advertising advertising2 advertising_adst… advertising2_ads…
#  <chr>      <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>             <dbl>             <dbl>
#1 adstock_…    500        118.         43.9              147.              54.9
#2 adstock_…    500        120.        231.               150.             289. 
#3 adstock_…    500        126.         76.8              157.              96.0
```

Comment: this is great! Thank you. Is there a way to have this in one dataframe in the end rather than a list? The adstock_0.5_0_0.7 would be tacked on to the column name applied to it so there are no duplicates column headers like: "advertising_adstock_0.5_0_0.7", "advertising2_adstock_0.5_0_0.7", etc. So that we know which combo is being applied to which column?

Comment: @nak5120 Yes, we can do `bind_rows(lst, .id = 'grp')`

Comment: It is better to have as a separate column as I mentioned instead of changing the column names and that will also create problems while joining into a single dataset

Comment: thank you! would you be able to provide that in columns rather than rows? so it would be "advertising_adstock_0.5_0_0.7". The row count will be way too large doing it by rows

Comment: It will make it difficult for you because then you will have to keep it in a list instead of a single dataset

Comment: I will use that for short term which works but I think in the long run it's going to be tough. Will accept the answer though. Thanks!

Comment: What I meant is that if you are going to process the data in the way you wanted, it still needs to be tidied up for all the processes and then you may again want to change it to the `bind_rows` way

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: would you actually be able to show it in column form with it looking like "advertiser2_adstock_..."? We need to run a regression equation with this and I don't think it will be possible to do that in this format

Comment: @nak5120  Could you please update the format of columns you need when it is a single dataset

Comment: I actually figured it out, there's probably a better way but will post my answer in a couple hours

Comment: @nak5120  It is good to know that you figured it out.  In most situations, when we think about making a reproducible example would  trigger some ideas

Comment: let me know what you think of this answer

Comment: follow up question here if interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50372119/apply-2-for-loops-to-same-column

Comment: @nak5120  Thanks, looks like it is deleted

Comment: figured it out on my own. Sorry about that @akrun

Comment: No need for sorry.  I am glad that you were able to figure it by yourself.  It will increase your knowledge greatly

Answer (score 1):

To add on to @akrun's answer. If we wanted to have it in column form this is how you would do it. @akrun if you think there is a better way, let me know:

```
test<-out %>%
  gather(var, value, -(id:Region)) %>%
  unite(var, var, id, sep="_") %>%
  spread(var, value)
colnames(test)
colnames(test) = gsub("_adstock_", "+", colnames(test))
colnames(test) = gsub("^(?!.*adstocked)([^+]*)\\+.*","\\1", colnames(test), perl=TRUE)

non_dupe<-test[!duplicated(as.list(test))]
```